# Unable to retrieve specific value from a jQuery object

Tags: jquery, object

I have a varying amount of divs that are constantly moving around the page, and I eventually need to draw lines between the divs as they move. To work towards this, I'm trying to store current positions for each div in their own objects. This will (hopefully) allow me to retrieve the position values and put them into this plugin (https://github.com/tbem/jquery.line).

I'm able to store the data that I need and then return the entire object, but when I try to return a specific value I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined .

This is the relevant part of the code I'm trying to use: http://pastebin.com/ra3WTATZ . The code is part of an .animate() function, and the overall code it quite long. If you need to see more, just let me know.

The problem seems to revolve around me using the 'dynamically' obtained div IDs. If I use the code below, it works fine.

```
$('div').data( 'test', { x: xCenter, y: yCenter } );
console.log($('div').data( 'test' ).x)
```

To do what I want, I believe I'll need to store the data on each specific div so I can call the specific data back as needed. I need the lines I draw to go through the divs in order (not randomly).

I am new to this type of thing, so maybe there's a better way to go about it. I'm trying to do it on my own so I learn, but I'm open to suggestions if I'm going in the completely wrong direction.

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT**
Despite the comments below, I did not figure out the issue. The order my scripts were called only fixed the problem for the first div.

Here is my entire script file: http://pastebin.com/tghSDPQT

The code I'm working with for storing data starts around line 75.

Comment: try `console.log($('#'+id).data( 'test' ).x)`

Comment: Seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/tznsax6b/ . The problem that you are facing is that the object is undefined. In other words: the id is wrong. I've checked out your pastebin line 10. You are calling `$('#' + id).data( 'test', { x: xCenter, y: yCenter } );`. At this point there is no div with id `$('#' + id)`. When you see console errors like `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined` it's clear that the object is not defined.

Comment: If I use `console.log(id)` the console is filled with all the id's of the divs as they animate (without the #). I'm not sure if that changes anything. Using `console.log($('#'+id).data( 'test' ).x)` still comes back with the same error. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the use of storing the data like this, but I'm hoping to retrieve the x and y values separately for any of the divs on demand, not necessarily all the divs at once. Thanks for the continued help. I can also provide more of the code if that will help.

Comment: I believe I figured out the issue. My script that gave the divs their IDs was being called after the script that ran the animation. So for the first few frames of the animation the divs had no IDs. It was a split second, but enough to kill the whole script with regards to storing the postions. (Something no one else could have known because I didn't post my entire setup, sorry about that!)

Comment: False alarm, the order my scripts were loading only "fixed" the issue for the first div. I've added a link to my entire script to my question.